# Merge audio and video, and add an overlay on top of it with FFMpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm programming a simple script in Python to make a video from a static image with an mp3, and add an overlay on top of it.
This overlay is a video, transparent or black (Screen) for example a logo that moves.

The overlay duration is 5minutes.
All my mp3 are under 5min (generally 2-3min), so the video should have the duration of the audio, not the overlay.
The overlay size is always 1920x1080, as well as my image so I don't have to deal with resolutions.

I'm using raw FFMpeg command to achieve it, but I'm stuck to filter_complex things, in order to add the overlay. The docs seems so complicated, I can't get it.
Here is what I have:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -loop 1 -i nature.jpg -i nature_sound.mp3 -acodec copy \
       -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p nature_video.mp4
```

How to add an MP4 video overlay on top of the nature.jpg, and the whole video having only the sound of nature_sound.mp3? I would like to learn those filter complex, if anyone can help me with some details it would be great! Thank you.

[updated command]

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -loop 1 -i ./nature.jpg -i ./overlay.mp4 -i nature_sound.mp3 \
  -filter_complex "[1]setsar=sar=1,format=rgba [video]; [0][video]blend=all_mode=screen[out]" \
  -map [out] output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
ffmpeg ... -i nature.jpg -i nature_sound.mp3 -i overlay.mp4 \
  -filter_complex [0:v][2:v]overlay ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
This is what I tried :
ffmpeg -r 25 -loop 1 -i ./nature.jpg -i ./nature_sound.mp3 -i ./overlay.mp4 -filter_complex " [0:v][2:v] overlay=0:0" output.mp4

This results in an MP4 with the audio, but the video is only the overlay : black background with logo animation. I think I should force screen mode, so this is what I tried :
ffmpeg -r 25 -loop 1 -i ./nature.jpg -i ./overlay.mp4 -i nature_sound.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]setsar=sar=1,format=rgba [video]; [0][video]blend=all_mode=screen[out]" -map [out] output.mp4

Comment: Now I have a MP4 video with my image and the overlay, but screen mode makes my pink all pink, such as this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045413/ffmpeg-screen-blending-mode-makes-transparent-png-pink , this is why I put format=rgba but it doesn't work. I don't have any audio too...

Comment: Once you put one `-map` option, you need to specify all your output streams. So add `-map [2:a]` to include the audio

Comment: As for the color, your issue appears to me that the overlay video is not "transparent" as you claimed in the OP. It sounds like you fabricated the overlay video yourself. I'd suggest go back to how you encoded it to enable transparency (cannot use x264 codec tho as it doesn't support alpha, maybe just a collection of PNG files...)

Comment: Last, if the background of the overlay is black, then maybe using the [`colorkey`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey) filter does the job (+ the `overlay` filter)

Comment: Everything is working. Thank you!